# Insert masivo random con Bulk collect y forall en oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

para cuestiones de simulaciones estoy intentando una tabla de usuarios con al menos 6 millones de registros de manera mas rápida usando bulk collect y forall, de los códigos que adapte este me funciono una sola vez y luego no entendi porque dejo de funcionar. aca dejo el codigo usado

```
DECLARE
TYPE matriz_rowid IS TABLE OF ROWID;
TYPE matriz_USU_CI IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_CI%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_P_NOMBRE IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_P_NOMBRE%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_S_NOMBRE IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_S_NOMBRE%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_P_APELLIDO IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_P_APELLIDO%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_S_APELLIDO IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_S_APELLIDO%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_FECHA_NAC IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_FECHA_NAC%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_PASAPORTE IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_PASAPORTE%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_PROFESION IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_PROFESION%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_TELEFONO IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_TELEFONO%TYPE;
TYPE matriz_USU_CORREO IS TABLE OF usuario.USU_CORREO%TYPE;  

CURSOR cur IS SELECT rowid,USU_ci,USU_p_nombre,USU_S_NOMBRE,USU_P_apellido,USU_S_apellido,USU_fecha_nac,USU_pasaporte,USU_profesion,USU_telefono,USU_correo
    FROM usuario;
    m_rowid matriz_rowid;
    m_USU_CI matriz_USU_CI;
    m_USU_P_NOMBRE matriz_USU_P_NOMBRE;
    m_USU_S_NOMBRE matriz_USU_S_NOMBRE;
    m_USU_P_APELLIDO matriz_USU_P_APELLIDO;
    m_USU_S_APELLIDO matriz_USU_S_APELLIDO;
    m_USU_FECHA_NAC matriz_USU_FECHA_NAC;
    m_USU_PASAPORTE matriz_USU_PASAPORTE;
    m_USU_PROFESION matriz_USU_PROFESION;
    m_USU_TELEFONO matriz_USU_TELEFONO;
    m_USU_CORREO matriz_USU_CORREO;
    contador NUMBER := 100;

BEGIN
  OPEN cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur BULK COLLECT
      INTO m_rowid,m_USU_ci,m_USU_p_nombre,m_USU_S_NOMBRE,m_USU_P_apellido,m_USU_S_apellido,m_USU_fecha_nac,m_USU_pasaporte,m_USU_profesion,m_USU_telefono,m_USU_correo LIMIT contador;
    FOR i IN 1 .. m_rowid.count
    LOOP
        m_USU_CI(i) := i;
        m_USU_P_NOMBRE(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('z',8);
        m_USU_S_NOMBRE(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('z',8);
        m_USU_P_APELLIDO(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('z',8);
        m_USU_S_APELLIDO(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('z',8);
        m_USU_FECHA_NAC(i) := TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2000-01-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '1950-12-31','J'))),'J');
        m_USU_PASAPORTE(i) := NULL;
        m_USU_PROFESION(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('z',10);
        m_USU_TELEFONO(i) := telefonos(telefono('Celular',floor(dbms_random.value(1000000,9999999))),telefono('Casa',floor(dbms_random.value(1000000,9999999))));
        m_USU_CORREO(i) := correos(DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('z',10)||'@gmail.com');
    END LOOP;
    FORALL i IN 1 .. m_rowid.count
      UPDATE usuario
        SET USU_CI = m_USU_CI(i),
            USU_P_NOMBRE = m_USU_P_NOMBRE(i),
            USU_S_NOMBRE = m_USU_S_NOMBRE(i),
            USU_P_APELLIDO = m_USU_P_APELLIDO(i),
            USU_S_APELLIDO = m_USU_S_APELLIDO(i),
            USU_FECHA_NAC = m_USU_FECHA_NAC(i),
            USU_PASAPORTE = m_USU_PASAPORTE(i),
            USU_PROFESION = m_USU_PROFESION(i),
            USU_TELEFONO = m_USU_TELEFONO(i),
            USU_CORREO = m_USU_CORREO(i)
        WHERE rowid = m_rowid(i);
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
END;
```

de antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Saludos, por una parte es importante aclarar que cuando usas el bulk con limitador (en tu caso 100) este funciona diferente en el for y en el forall, que ocurre, con el forall procesa lotes de n registros hasta que recorre todo el cursor, en el caso del for solo va a tomar los primeros n del cursor y los demas no los procesa. Te aconsejo replantear esa parte

Comment: gracias por esa aclaratoria amigo... el problema que tengo con este código es que como hago el collect de una tabla que esta vacia... el conteo de los ciclos for queda en cero y me causa error cuando intento modificarlo con algo diferente que no venga del cursor